# How to prove this strange combinatorical identity?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I observed today that
$$1+n+\sum_{i_1=1}^ni_1+\sum_{i_2=1}^{n}\sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2}i_1+\sum_{i_3=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_3}\sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2}i_1+\dots + \sum_{i_{n-1}}^n\sum_{i_{n-2}=1}^{i_{n-1}}\dots\sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2}i_1=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$
I'm wondering how this identity can be proven. Note that there are $n+1$ terms on the LHS.

Comment: The right side is $(n+1)C_n$, where $C_n$ is the Catalan number. So it looks like the left side counts the number of catalan paths, with multiplicity. I'd guess that multiplicity is from where the path makes its first turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the initial $1$ on the LHS, you can write the $k^{th}$ term on the LHS as
$$
\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}}i_k=\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}}\sum_{i_{k+1}=1}^{i_k}1
$$
Since we are summing the number $1$, the value of the summation is just equal to the number of ways to choose the indices.

A choice of indices is a weakly decreasing list $n\ge i_1\ge i_2\ge \dots \ge i_k\ge i_{k+1}\ge 1$. Choosing these is equivalent to choosing a multi-set of $[n]$ of size $k+1$, the number of which is $\binom{n+k}{n-1}$. Therefore, the LHS is
$$
1+\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n+1}{n-1}+\dots+\binom{2n-1}{n-1},
$$
and the result follows by the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Answer (score 2):

Fix $1\leqslant p\leqslant 2n$ and let $A_p$ denote the number of ways to choose an $n$ element subset $T$ of $\{1, \ldots, 2n\}$ with $\max T=p$. Note that $A_p=0$ for $p<n$, $A_n=1$, and for $1\leqslant j\leqslant n$, $$A_{n+j}=\sum_{i_j=1}^n\ldots \sum_{i_2=1}^{i_3} \sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2}1 = \sum_{i_j=1}^n\ldots \sum_{i_2=1}^{i_3}i_2.$$  Summing over $p$ gives the number of $n$ element subsets of $2n$, which is $\binom{2n}{n}$, your right side, and it is also equal to $\sum_{p=n}^{2n}A_p$, which is your left side.

Comment: +1, But I think it is not quite so obvious why $A_{n+j}$ is equal to the number of subsets with maximum $n+j$. What do the numbers $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_j$ represent?

Comment: It was obvious enough to me that that's what the left side was counting without interpreting the indices. But I came up with: Computing $A_{n+j}$ involves counting a certain number of sets $T$ with $|T|=n$ and $\max T=n+j$, which is the same as counting the distinct sets $\{1, \ldots, n+j\}\setminus T$. Thus we can count the number of $j$ element subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n+j-1\}$. If $U=\{t_1, \ldots, t_j\}$ with $t_1<\ldots <t_j$ is such a set, $i_k=t_k-k+1$  gives a $1$-$1$ correspondence to the indices that the sum $\sum_{i_j=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_2=1}^{i_3}\sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2}1$ is counting.